# Solving poisson equation on image with neumann boundary condition

Tags: matlab, finite-difference

I am trying to solve a standard Poisson equation on image with Neumann boundary condition. The Poisson equation has the form:

$Δp=b$

where $b$ is the divergence of the input image,which is as shown:
[image]

I tried to write it in Matlab with centred finite difference method and Gauss-Seidel iterative method but the result turns out to be very weird, which is as shown:
[image]

Can any kind soul help to spot errors in my code below:

```
{%Specifying parameters
nx=rows;                           %Number of steps in space(x)(vertical)
ny=columns;                        %Number of steps in space(y)(horizontal)
dx=1;
dy=1;
h=dx;




%Solving (Dxx+Dyy)p(i,j)=b(i,j) (eqn 3.16) using centred FDM (5-points difference)
%Gauss-Seidel iterative method
pn=zeros(nx,ny);                 %Preallocating pn
p=zeros(nx,ny);                  %Preallocating p
b=zeros(nx,ny);
ax=0;                            %counter 

for j=2:ny-1
   for i=2:nx-1
   b(i,j)=0.5*(grayImage1(i+1,j)-grayImage1(i-1,j)+grayImage(i,j+1)-grayImage(i,j-1))./h;

   end
end 

i=2:nx-1; 
j=2:ny-1;
for it=1:200000
        p(1,1)=0;        
        pn=p;   
        p(i,j)=0.25*(((pn(i+1,j)+p(i-1,j)))+((pn(i,j+1)+p(i,j-1)))-h^2*(b(i,j)));

    %%boundary conditions 
    %The four corners
    %p(1,1)=1/2*pn(2,1)+1/2*pn(1,2)-1/4*dx^2*b(1,1);            
    p(1,ny)=1/2*pn(2,ny)+1/2*pn(1,ny-1)-1/4*dx^2*b(1,ny);            
    p(nx,1)=1/2*pn(nx,2)+1/2*pn(nx-1,1)-1/4*dx^2*b(nx,1);          
    p(nx,ny)=1/2*pn(nx-1,ny)+1/2*pn(nx,ny-1)-1/4*dx^2*b(nx,ny);

    %The four sides
    p(1,j)=1/4*(2*pn(2,j)+pn(1,j+1)+pn(1,j-1)-dx^2*b(1,j));            
    p(nx,j)=1/4*(2*pn(nx-1,j)+pn(nx,j+1)+pn(nx,j-1)-dx^2*b(nx,j));            
    p(i,1)=1/4*(2*pn(i,2)+pn(i+1,1)+pn(i-1,1)-dy^2*b(i,1));
    p(i,ny)=1/4*(2*pn(i,ny-1)+pn(i+1,ny)+pn(i-1,ny)-dy^2*b(i,ny));

    if abs(p(i,j)-pn(i,j))<=zeros(nx-2,ny-2)+0.0001
        break
    end
    ax=ax+1
end }
```

Thanks very much!!

p/s: I do notice that pure Neumann boundary condition will give rise to non-unique solutions. Hence I followed one of the advice from other answers to set one of the corner to zero. Unfortunately it seems to have no effect on the results.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the result turns out to be very weird"? Knowing *how* a solution is wrong often tells a lot about where the bug could be.

Comment: As a side note: The proper spelling of the name is "Seidel", not "Seidler".

Answer (score 3):

I cannot recommend fixing a corner to zero, that changes the problem you are trying to solve, instead just add before you iterate a line with:

```
b = b - mean(b);
```

This is called the Discrete Compatibility Criteria. May I refer to my own answer to the following: [Solving a linear equation system with pure Neumann condition](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/19807/solving-a-linear-equation-system-with-pure-neumann-condition/25933#25933)

In an effort to make this an answer, the following code will generate the matrix version of your code and let you use e.g. conjugate gradient as a solver. I grabbed it out of some of the code on: http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.086/2008/
It combines two 1d matrices for the all-Neumann Poisson problem into a large matrix for the 2d problem using the Kronecker Product:

```
maxit = 1000;
tol = 1e-6;

e = ones(nx-4,1);
A1= spdiags([1 -1 1; e*[1 -2 1]; 1 -1 1],-1:1,nx-2,nx-2); %/dx^2;
e = ones(ny-4,1);
A2= spdiags([1 -1 1; e*[1 -2 1]; 1 -1 1],-1:1,ny-2,ny-2); %/dy^2;
A = -( kron(speye(ny-2),A1)+kron(A2,speye(nx-2)) ); clear A1 A2
b = reshape(b,(nx-2)*(ny-2),1);
b = b - mean(b);

x = pcg(A,b,tol,maxit);

x = reshape(x,nx-2,ny-2);
```