# Conjugate Gradient for singular 2D poisson finite element with Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: convergence, scipy, conjugate-gradient

**Heavily edited question after I realised partly what the problem was**

I have programmed a simple 2D square finite element solution to the Poisson equation

$-\Delta u = f$

The source function integrates to zero and I'm implementing as natural boundary conditions. This leads to a tridiagonal block matrix structure. 
As follows:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
D_e & T_1 &  &    \\\
T_1 & D  & T_1 &    \\\
& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots  \\\
& &  T_1 & D_e
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$A$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite, but singular (invariant under transformations of $u+c$
Since $\int_\Omega f dx = 0$ I don't do anything on the right hand side to implement $\int_{\partial \Omega} g dx = 0$.

Of course the system is not uniquely solvable (up to a constant) so I included a row of 1s on the bottom of the sparse matrix to represent $\int_\Omega u dx = 0$. I also add a column of ones on the right side to represent the lagrangian to solve for (?). The bottom right corner is a zero.

[This answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21946/32953) has some information about how my system is setup.

Anyway it is no problem to solve the sparse system using scipy's library.  The result is as follows:
[image: Solution using scipy'S spsolve]

Now see the result when I try to solve with my own CG method or that of scipy, similar result:

[image: CG approximation of solution]
The blocks clearly have a drop in value at their centres.

Anybody have experience similar to this? Any ideas what I've done wrong? I'm using `np.linalg.cond`  and have found that the condition number is 626.

The error sometimes jumps upwards which seems incorrect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before I accept my own answer, I will wait to see if someone else can shine light on this...

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the eigenvalues produced by `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` and `np.linalg.eig` and noticed that in the process of modifying the stiffness matrix, the 0 eigenvalue is removed but two new eigenvalues appear at $\pm \sqrt n$ where n is the size of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

So the matrix now has a negative eigenvalue.  Solution to this was to use a `scipy.sparse.linalg.bicgstab` gradient method which produced the following and is better but not really great:

[image]

Solution was to code my own Biconjugate Gradient Stabilised which led to this:

[image: Soln with self programmed BiCGstab]

for a different (randomly generated) source:

[image: Source map for previous soln]